# Derived category of representations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

Suppose we are given an algebraic group $G$ (linearly reductive). Let $D^b(Repr(G))$ be the bounded derived category of finite dimensional algebraic representations of $G$. I am intressted in tilting objects for this category. Is there something known...some reference or articles treating this problem?

Comment: The category is semisimple --- just take the sum of all simple representations.

Comment: Ok. But the number of these simple representations may be infinite right? Are there some nontrivial tilting objects known for certain groups?

Comment: If the number of simple objects is infinite, then there  is no finite dimensional tilting generator (for any finite dimensional representation there is a simple object which is not its summand and so it is in the orthogonal).

Comment: Do you assume the tilting object is a finite dimensional representation...I mean the tilting object could be a komplex in  $D^b(Repr(G))$... So what is when $G$ is not assumed to be linearly reductive?

Comment: If it is a complex with finite number of finite-dimensional cohomology, still there are only finitely many simple summands in those and everything missing is in the orthogonal.

Comment: @Aleksa: In characteristic 0 it's usually simpler just to study one block of representations at a time.  On the other hand, for reductive groups in prime characteristic (not linearly reductive), the module categories get much more interesting and there are injectives, tilting objects, etc.  In either situation there is a lot of literature out there.

Comment: That's nice. Can you please give me some titles of the literature?

Comment: The book of Jantzen is a good starting point.

Comment: @Aleksa: Jantzen's book covers much of the modular representation theory.  Derived categories come up mostly when you translate into algebraic geometry, as people like Bezrukavnikov and Mirkovic have done in their papers (see arXiv).  It does get complicated.